# Linux Kiosk software?

Tags: linux, flash, kiosk

My team is tasked with migrating a full screen, kiosk-style application for playing back media files, from windows to embedded ARM Linux (thin client). We need to support mpeg-2 playback in sd/1080p as well as display of HTML, SWF.

Videos will be called from flash but can’t be played in flash (content is mpeg-2, flash won’t play mpeg-2). They will need to be played by a video player app/plugin on the embedded linux box.

I've looked at some of the packages for Linux. I'm not seeing anything that would let flash call an external application or have that video played by another plugin. Hardware has no CD, so a boot from CD system is out.

So I am soliciting recommendations specifically on the following points:

1. Video player: Right now I’m having luck with MPlayer on our thin client, any other video players I should be considering?
2. Linux kiosk package: is there a package out there that will allow us to display a full screen browser on boot up and allow the flash player to have the playing of mpeg-2 video handled by another application or plugin without removing the flash web site from memory to do it?

Broadly speaking, given the requirements, what would you use?

I appreciate any answers you might have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research r-kisok for Firefox is the best bet I've seen. It is able to pin the browser to full screen and reduce access to the host OS. It blocks command keys etc. There's a lot to like. I grabbed a copy of r-kiosk and started modifying the settings. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/r-kiosk/